# Android saving activity state on sql lite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-activity

I have one activity which is connected to a web service and receive "events" from other users of my app, in this activity i have Recycler view that creates a cardview every time the user receive and event. When an event is received, my activity creates a countdown that limit the user's time to participate in the event. My doubt  is how do i save the current events that the user are viewing while he is on the app, i want to control when the user minimize the app. I'm planning to save the events in sql lite database, every time an event is received add it to the database, and when the resumes my app, load the data and show them again (and clean the expired ones). Does this have any performance issues? Or it is better is use the bundle object?.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sounds like you overwrite this two methods

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // load events from database to memory5.000-
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    // delete events in memory
}
```

"Does this have any performance issues?" If the the number of events your want to store in DB isn't so great(<100-200MB storage space needed), the performance shouldn't suffer greatly (with a good access implentation to the DB).